# Is it possible to delete an specific blob after a certain number of days? Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have been through the documentation of [Azure Lifecycle Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal) and as far as I understand, the policies we make from Azure Lifecycle Management are applied through out the container or applied on all blobs with a specific prefix. However what I am trying to achieve is being able to delete an specific blob after a certain number of days.

For example I have a blob named: `my-container/my-blob.txt` and I would like this blob to be deleted after 5 days, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

The lifecycle management policy is available with General Purpose v2 (GPv2) accounts, Blob storage accounts, and Premium Block Blob storage accounts, you just need to upgrade an existing General Purpose (GPv1) account to a GPv2 account.

In blobTypes choose type same as the time you are creating your blob:
available types are:

1. blockBlob
2. appendBlob
3. pageBlob

Then apply this policy:

```
{
"rules": [{
    "name": "ruleFoo",
    "enabled": true,
    "type": "Lifecycle",
    "definition": {
        "filters": {
            "blobTypes": ["blockBlob"],
            "prefixMatch": ["my-container/my-blob.txt"]
        },
        "actions": {
            "baseBlob": {
                "delete": {
                    "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: which blobs is this policy going to delete? all blobs in `my-container` or only the `my-container/my-blob.txt` blob?

Comment: This policy will delete all blobs in `my-container` if you want to specify a blob modify `prefixMatch` property according to your situation

Comment: I am looking for something with which I can delete 1 specific blob in a container or in a directory, as already mentioned in my question. Not looking to delete a subset of blobs.

Comment: yes, you can do it just set this to `"prefixMatch": ["my-container/my-blob.txt"]`. I have also edited my policy in my answer.